# Model creation depends on other model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have an Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :title
end
```

And a Book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :plot

  belongs_to_ :item
end
```

I want to be able to create a book by using

```
Book.new(:title=>"Title", :author=>"Author", :plot=>"BlaBla")
Book.save
```

And it will create an Item with the title and author, and also create a Book with the created Item ID.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:after_create` callback and virtual_attributes as follows.

In you book model write this

```
attr_accessor :title, :author

attribute_accessible :title, :author, :plot

after_create :create_item

def create_item
  item = self.build_item(:title => self.title, :author => self.author)
  item.save
end
```

Comment: But here book.item_id will be nil because book was saved first and at that time item_id was nil (item was not exist).

Comment: Did you tried doing this? It shouldn't happen cause when you are creating the item via book object the id gets saved automatically. Tell me if it doesn't work.

Comment: @SuperEngineer Why not using before_create and then setting the item_id?

Comment: @SuperEngineer Yes before_create or before_save will work properly.

Comment: I've edited the answer. There were some errors in the previous one. You can use before_create also. In that you should first create item and set the item_id of book in the before_create callback.

Comment: @SuperEngineer Actually I'm getting ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity on setting item attributes.

Comment: That's just because :title and :author are not included in the attribute_accessible list in your book model.

Comment: It's very common error. read here to get some idea. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Answer (score 1):

Using before_save or before_create

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author

  before_save :create_item

  #before_create :create_item

  def create_item
    if self.title.present? && self.autor.present?
      item = Item.new(:title => self.title, :author => self.author)
      item.save(:validate => false)
      self.item = item # or self.item_id = item.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually I'm getting ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity on setting item attributes.